# Alter data type from column in database

Tags: mysql, database, types, sqldatatypes

I would like to change the data type of a variable from a table in a database. The type of data I want to change belongs to the variable 'exercise_id', from **INT** to **INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT**. The problem is that 'exercise_id' is PRIMARY KEY and I'm afraid to destroy the table because I do not want to lose data. Do you know any way to alter the data type without deleting anything? Thank you. I'm using MySQL with the software MySQL Workbench 6.3

THE TABLE I HAVE:

```
CREATE TABLE exercises (
    exercise_id INT,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    text text,
     PRIMARY KEY(exercise_id)
);
```

THE TABLE I WANT:

```
CREATE TABLE exercises (
    exercise_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    text text,
    PRIMARY KEY(exercise_id)
);
```

Could it be done like this?

```
ALTER TABLE exercises MODIFY exercise_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: We need to know which dialect of sql and which database engine you are using. A primary key should already be not null, but without this information we cannot predict what will happen when we set auto_increment.

Comment: @AWhitePelican I'm using MySQL with the software MySQL Workbench 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you showed yourself, the line

```
ALTER TABLE exercises MODIFY exercise_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

can indeed be used to make the changes you need. `NOT NULL` should not change anything as the field is already a primary key. The `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not restrictive: it will not check if all ids are incremental, you can even add your own id as long as it unique.

You will need to think about future necessities of your table. It maybe is beneficial to regenerate your id column to make full use of the auto increment feature. This is very specific to the use case though.